# CSS unwanted spacing between anchor-tag elements

Tags: html, css, anchor, margin

I have this stylesheet:

```
*{
    padding: 0px;
    margin: 0px;
}

a{

  background:yellow;

}
```

and this webpage:

```
<a href="/blog/">Home</a>
<a href="/about/">About</a>
<a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
```

Results in:

[image]

How do I make those anchor tag to "touch" each other,removing that unwanted space in-between?

thanks
Luca

Comment: Newlines, in most HTML context, create a space in the rendered view.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You need to remove the whitespace (in this case the newline) between your  tags. Some browsers render it as a space.

Comment: I thought all browsers collapse whitespace into one space character? Which ones do not do this? (I'm not trying to discredit you, I'm genuinely interested.)

Comment: Some = all, apparently. ;) I do not have experience with every web browser, so I didn't make a sweeping statement...

Comment: That's part of the HTML standard - whitespace is condensed down to one space.

Answer (score 35):

You can use this trick to get rid of the space:

HTML:

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="/blog/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about/">About</a>
    <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>   
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#test { font-size:0; }
#test a { font-size:16px; background:yellow; }
```

**Live demo:** http://jsfiddle.net/quucy/

Comment: Be careful with this code because it might be interpreted by web crawlers as abuse since you are explicitly hiding text inside an element containing links. Its true that the links itself are visible thanks to a higher specificity rule but still web crawlers see a bunch of links inside a container which tells all of its ancestors to hide their textual content.

Comment: @holodoc Do you know of any articles that go into detail about this? How real is this problem?

Comment: @aaaidan That would be a good question for [Matt Cutts](http://www.youtube.com/user/GoogleWebmasterHelp) `:)`

Comment: Also I had issues with it no longer breaking up the links, they all were displayed on one line since the line breaks were 0. I make the #test element font-size: 1px; and the problem went away.

Answer (score 19):

I think I might find a pretty cool way to solve it :-). I started with the fact of using `<!-- comments -->` to fill empty `< span >`s etc.

So if you want to keep your anchor-on-a-new-line structure and do not want the spaces between them... simply open a block comment on the end of the line and end it on the new line just before new `< anchor >`

Like this:

```
<div id="test">
    <a href="/blog/">Home</a><!--
    --><a href="/about/">About</a><!--
    --><a href="/contact/">Contact</a>   
</div>
```

and DEMO: http://jsfiddle.net/Lukis/reZG2/1/

Comment: Thank you for this brilliant solution!

Answer (score 4):

The space between the links might be produced by newline characters you have in your code but it really depends in which browser you get this behavior (some browser ignore these characters some do not).

Try putting all three  tags in a single line and without spaces between them.

```
<a href="/blog/">Home</a><a href="/about/">About</a><a href="/contact/">Contact</a>
```

Answer (score 4):

How about puting them in ul/li structure?

```css
#test li {
    background:yellow; 
    float: left;
    list-style: none;
}
```

```html
<ul id="test">
  <li><a href="/blog/">Home</a></li>
  <li><a href="/about/">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: I think this is actually the best solution because ul>li should be used for nav links anyway as it's best for accessibility.

Comment: What element do you want to use in a `li` that is forbidden? I think you can use most available elements. See [the specs](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/grouping-content.html#the-li-element). The content model is 'Flow content' , which means you can use most elements available in the body.

Answer (score 2):

All the above answers show some neat ways of getting rid of that unwanted whitespace but I don't see the one I've been using for almost a decade; so here's another simple solution to your very old problem for people who still wrestle with that whitespace -- **use float!**

`HTML:`

```
<div id="test">
  <a href="/blog/">Home</a>
  <a href="/about/">About</a>
  <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>   
</div>
```

`CSS:`

```
#test { 
  overflow:hidden; 
 /* this isn't really required here but helps; 
 or use your preferred method for clearfix  */
}

#test a { 
  float:left; 
  background: yellow;
}
```

`jsfiddle:`
http://jsfiddle.net/fjj7dsyx/2/

Comment: FrankieDoodie's latest answer using flexbox is the recommended solution now IMO.

Answer (score 1):

You can use flexbox:

```css
div {
    display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div>
    <a href="/blog/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about/">About</a>
    <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>   
</div>
```

Or if you use Bootstrap:

```html
<div class="d-flex">
    <a href="/blog/">Home</a>
    <a href="/about/">About</a>
    <a href="/contact/">Contact</a>   
</div>
```