# ng-repeat broke bootstrap styles in .form-inline

Tags: angularjs, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to add buttons to my inline form using `ng-repeat` directive.
It is working but buttons lose spacing between them when using `ng-repeat`.
If I remove `ng-repeat` and just add exactly identical html for buttons myself then spacing between buttons is ok.

Here is [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2ehzyzko/2/).

If is very strange as resulting html is absolutely identical.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let's take a look at the *rendered* HTML...

First the non-angular:

```
<div class="form-inline">

    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span>123</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span>123</span>
        </button>
    </div>
    <div class="button-wrapper">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span>123</span>
        </button>
    </div>

</div>
```

And now the Angular:

```
<div class="form-inline ng-scope" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <!-- ngRepeat: button in buttons --><div class="button-wrapper ng-scope" ng-repeat="button in buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="ng-binding">123</span>
        </button>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: button in buttons --><div class="button-wrapper ng-scope" ng-repeat="button in buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="ng-binding">456</span>
        </button>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: button in buttons --><div class="button-wrapper ng-scope" ng-repeat="button in buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span class="ng-binding">789</span>
        </button>
    </div><!-- end ngRepeat: button in buttons -->

</div>
```

See the difference? There are line breaks and code alignment spaces between the button-wrapper divs in the hand-typed HTML, but none in the HTML rendered by the ng-repeat. Those line breaks and spaces are visually rendered as a single space between each div. This can be demonstrated by removing the line breaks between the divs on the hand-typed HTML. I believe the intention of bootstrap is to render without space between buttons unless explicitly defined.

[This other question addresses how to eliminate the spaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13063076/line-breaks-between-divs-render-a-space-how-to-eliminate-it-from-html)

Answer (score 1):

I see the example in fiddle but if you remove the div line get the same alination.

however I was having many problems with the Bootstrap styles in ng-repeat in my case the solution was put the `style="display: inline-block;"` in the div with the ng-repeat directive

```
<div class="button-wrapper" ng-repeat="button in buttons" style="display: inline-block;">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
        <span>{{button}}</span>
    </button>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Lathejockey81 answer I finally realized a valid solution.
After each button except last we need to insert an empty `div` with `display: inline-block`. This div must be last tag inside the `ng-repeat`ed tag.

```
<div class="form-inline" ng-controller="MyCtrl">

    <div class="button-wrapper" ng-repeat="button in buttons">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">
            <span>{{button}}</span>
        </button>
        <div ng-show="!$last" style="display: inline-block;"></div>
    </div>

</div>
```

Updated working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2nb3j054/1/).