# Images not centering correctly in div

Tags: html, css, center, margins

I have a div with 5 images in a row that are 300px each. With a 10px margin on each side they should fit in my div at 1600px wide but the last image is bumping to the next line. Why is it not fitting? After some trial and error I see that when I adjust my margins to 8.5px they fit correctly but that doesn't seem to make sense?? I don't have any other borders, padding, etc.

Here is my CSS:

```
#wrap {
    width: 1600px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background-color: red;
}

.image {
    width: 300px;
    margin: 8px 10px 0 10px;
    vertical-align: text-top;
}
```

My HTML looks something like this:

```
<div id="wrap">
<div id="portfolio">
    <section>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
    </section>
    <section>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
        <a><img></a>
    </section>
</div>
```

Comment: There is no element with the `.image` class in your html?

Comment: Provide us jsfiddle.

Comment: You've posted a lot more HTML than you have CSS, so it's difficult for us to tell you what your problem is without making assumptions. You'll need to provide us with all of the CSS to go with the HTML, so that we can tell you what the problem is. With what you've posted, we'd just be guessing unfortunately.

Comment: duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**The reason for the issue:**

In your example code, it's actually making the whitespace between achors into spaces (which are 4px wide each).

So instead of just `anchor,anchor,anchor...`, it's actually displaying `anchor,space,anchor,space...` etc.

**Solution:**

You can either use images only (no anchors) and remove the whitespace between each, or you can float the anchors left:

```
a { float: left; }
```

Here's a functional JSfiddle where it shows that by removing the anchors and space between `<img>` tags, it allows them to be all in the same line even without floating:

https://jsfiddle.net/q6ubzp0t/

Comment: Thank you! The explanation was helpful - I didn't know anchors add the 4px white space (still learning!) I tested your suggestions and they did work but I can't remove the anchors as they are links, and floating messed up my formatting because I have various sizes of images. I wanted to keep the anchors on my html aligned though (instead of deleting the white space between them) because I need to be able to quickly find an image and replace if needed... I browsed some other pages and this seemed to work: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18300727/6114800 but is this considered "acceptable" code?

Comment: Actually, also tried making font-size: 0 on my #wrap and that seems to work better than cluttering up my html. Thanks again everyone!

Answer (score 1):

> ... but the last image is bumping to the next line. Why is it not
>   fitting?

The problem you encountered is [white-space margin](https://css-tricks.com/fighting-the-space-between-inline-block-elements/).

An inline element have a small margin on its right/bottom edge, making your calculation become wrong.

The simplest way to solve this is likely by setting `wrap` to `display: flex`

Answer (score -1):

Here is your solution
add this to your style and it will work fine

```
a{
  float: left;
}
```

Comment: Actually, although floating here is one option, it does not center the elements.